# Error on sqlite database creation - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to add a new column to my sqlite database. I have previously added an extra column (email) and have had no problem at all. Below is my DbHelper class for creation.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static String DATABASE_NAME="userdata";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="user";
public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
public static final String KEY_LNAME="lname";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL="email";
public static final String KEY_CHECK="check";
public static final String KEY_ID="id";
public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_LNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_CHECK+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

}
```

When the db is created it is displayed from my mainactivity:

```
private void displayData() {
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

    userId.clear();
    user_fName.clear();
    user_lName.clear();
    user_eMail.clear();
    user_cHeck.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
            user_fName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME)));
            user_lName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME)));
            user_eMail.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_EMAIL)));
            user_cHeck.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_CHECK)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(getActivity(),userId, user_fName, user_lName, user_eMail, user_cHeck);
    userList.setAdapter(disadpt);
    mCursor.close();
}
{

}
```

On creation i receive the following error:

```
04-09 15:33:16.740: E/SQLiteLog(19806): (1) near "TEXT": syntax error
04-09 15:33:16.755: W/dalvikvm(19806): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40df4a08)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TEXT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fname TEXT, lname TEXT, check TEXT)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:909)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:520)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1719)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1650)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at app.norman.tennis.fours.DbHelper.onCreate(DbHelper.java:23)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at app.norman.tennis.FoursFragment.displayData(FoursFragment.java:244)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at app.norman.tennis.FoursFragment.onResume(FoursFragment.java:235)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1828)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:921)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1437)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
04-09 15:33:16.765: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me understand why i am having this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHECK` is a reserved word in SQLite. Please choose a different name for this column. It will save you a lot of grief when creating other statements as well.

[link](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst)

Comment: Something so simple can drive a man so insane. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No kidding. I once spent hours debugging only to find a misplaced character in a SQL string. Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 1):

`check` is a reserved word in SQL. Either rename the column or quote it in `` ` ` `` backticks.